# Saving many screenshots consecutively with Texture2D.SaveAsPng causes out of memory exception

Tags: c#, xna, out-of-memory

When I make screenshots in my XNA game, each `texture.SaveAsPng` consumes some memory and it doesn't seem to return back to the game. So eventually I run out of memory. I tried saving the texture data into `FileStream` and `MemoryStream`, hoping I could save it from there as `Bitmap`, but the results are the same. Is there a way to forcefully free this memory or some workaround that will let me get image data and save it some other way without running into out of memory exception?

```
sw = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
sh = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;

int[] backBuffer = new int[sw * sh];
GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData(backBuffer);
using(Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, sw, sh, false,
  GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat))
{
    texture.SetData(backBuffer);
    using(var fs = new FileStream("screenshot.png", FileMode.Create))        
        texture.SaveAsPng(fs, sw, sh);  // ← this line causes memory leak      
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post a small example that produces the "Memory leak"?

Comment: can you show the code where you are saving the texture?

Comment: Is the texture `Texture2D` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to create the Bitmap from the texture bytes directly and bypass the internal method to check if the `SaveAsPng` is leaking or its something else.

Try This extension method (unfortunatly I cannot test (no xna at work) but it **should** work.)

```
public static class TextureExtensions
{
    public static void TextureToPng(this Texture2D texture, int width, int height, ImageFormat imageFormat, string filename)
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            byte blue;
            IntPtr safePtr;
            BitmapData bitmapData;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            byte[] textureData = new byte[4 * width * height];

            texture.GetData<byte>(textureData);
            for (int i = 0; i < textureData.Length; i += 4)
            {
                blue = textureData[i];
                textureData[i] = textureData[i + 2];
                textureData[i + 2] = blue;
            }
            bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            safePtr = bitmapData.Scan0;
            Marshal.Copy(textureData, 0, safePtr, textureData.Length);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            bitmap.Save(filename, imageFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Its a bit crude but you can clean it up (if it even works).

An last but not least (if all other attempts fail) you could call `GarbageCollection` yourself but this is NOT recommended as its pretty bad practice.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

The above code should be LAST resort only.

Good luck.

Comment: I went straight ahead and tried the GC methods which unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Then I made 108 screenshots with your code and it didn't ever consume more than 800 megabytes per 4096×4096 image, though it took quite some time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you, this work perfect. SaveAsPng memory leak was killing my project